# HTACCESS rewrite rule with query string

Tags: .htaccess

My problem is that when I try to redirect an address to file with adding query string after it, I get HTTP 500 error.

That's code of one

```
RewriteRule ^error-400/?$ httpErr.php?code=400
```

Comment: My fault, Unsupported HTTP response code 418

Comment: You need to trace it from where are you getting `418`